Setup Freeze created by Indigo Rose
I'm using Indigo Rose to create an installer for my software. The installation proceeds smoothly until the last DLL, at which point it completely freezes. The installer appears to hang and becomes unresponsive. However, if I force-close the setup and restart it, the installation resumes from where it left off and completes successfully.
Details:

Installer Software: Created with Indigo Rose
Operating System: Windows 10 / 11 Pro 64 Bit
Antivirus Software: Sophos (but the issue occurs even when disabled)
User: Installation was performed both as a regular user and as an administrator
Other Machines: The issue only occurs on specific machines, not on all

What I've Tried:

Restarting the computer
Running the installation as an administrator
Temporarily disabling the antivirus

I expect that the setup will finish without problem
